# python multiprocess requests on API

Tags: python-3.x, request, python-multiprocessing, pool

I need to get data from API which url based on different ID.

url = "http://123456789/"
id = "jimmy"

I have a list of ID, here are my code

```
for id in ID:
   response = requests.get(url+id)
   info = response.json(encoding = "utf-8")
   ##save info
```

But I have 400,000 ID and it will take to long to grab all data,
So I want use multiprocess to finish this job.
Cut the ID list into 10 or more small list and run them in the same time.
How can I do that?
Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pool. 
Cut the list of IDs into many subIds, and different process handle different ids.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Adding a code example will make this answer more understandable.